# Get value async function javascript

Tags: reactjs, firebase

variable check always return 0, authDefault.onAuthStateChanged call to firebase database after function return, how to fix? i want get value in firebase and set to variable check

[image]

Comment: are you sure the function that sets `check` to `1` or `2` is actually being invoked?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, it's called after the return

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider listening to @laptou and even your question already has been answered edit it and let people what was wrong in your code without opening an image. This helps other people are being benefited from your mistake easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
async function checkLogin() {

    const check = await new Promise(function (resolve) {

        authDefault.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {

            if (user) {
                resolve(1);
            }
            else {
                resolve(2);
            }
        });
    });

    return check;
}
```

Comment: yes, it working, but i can not set value function for variable. it issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfvu7.png

Comment: if the problem to your original question is solved, please mark the question as answered

Comment: please open another question for your next issue, rather than reuse this one